# React: on page load Fade image in

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to fade in images when the page finishes loading but it is not working. 
This is the code I am using:

```
import classNames from 'classnames';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM, { render } from 'react-dom';



var ImageComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      loaded: false
    };
  },

  onImageLoad: function() {
    if (this.isMounted()) {
      this.setState({ loaded: true });
    }
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    var imgTag = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.img);
    var imgSrc = imgTag.getAttribute('src');
    var img = new window.Image();
    img.onload = this.onImageLoad;
    img.src = imgSrc;
  },

  render: function() {
    var { className, ...props } = this.props;
    var imgClasses = 'image';
    var rootClassName = classNames(className, 'image', {
      'image-loaded': this.state.loaded,
    });

    return (
      <img ref="img" {...props} className={rootClassName} />
    );
  }
});

export default ImageComponent;
```

I then wrap ImageComponent around:

```
 <ImageComponent  src="http://voices.nationalgeographic.com/files/2013/04/NationalGeographic_1467467.jpg"/>
```

I set my css styling to:

```
.image { 
  opacity: 0; transition: opacity 5s;}

.image-loaded { opacity: 1; }
```

Now when I go and inspect the page, the image inherits the class names of "image" and "image-loaded" but there is no css3. The image loads right away without any transition. This is the link I used it from: http://buildwithreact.com/article/fade-in-image-recipe

Answer (score 3):

You can use the react-addons-css-transition-group 
first of all install the package:

```
$ npm install react-addons-css-transition-group --dev
```

In your component import the new package:

```
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group'
```

then where you use your component add the animation [as explained in the react docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html)

```
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup
  transitionName="example" transitionAppear={true}
  transitionAppearTimeout={700}>
   <ImageComponent src="http://voices.nationalgeographic.com/files/2013/04/NationalGeographic_1467467.jpg"/>
</ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
```

Now add in your css:

```
.example-appear {
  opacity: 0.01;
}

.example-appear.example-appear-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .7s ease-in;
}
```

Note that you need to use *-appear and *-appear-active class in order to use the power of the CSS Transition Group methods!

Comment: the image still loads right away when the page is loaded